# torch.manual_seed(seed) get RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am using GOOGLE COLAB when I get this error. Here is my code, I didn't find anything wrong, these code were right few hour ago but suddenly went wrong, I don't know why

```
import torch
if torch.cuda.is_available():       
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    print('There are %d GPU(s) available.' % torch.cuda.device_count())
    print('We will use the GPU:', torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
else:
    print('No GPU available, using the CPU instead.')
    device = torch.device("cpu")
seed=1
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
```

The error is

```
There are 1 GPU(s) available.
We will use the GPU: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-436d9d8bb120> in <module>()
      9 seed=1
     10 np.random.seed(seed)
---> 11 torch.manual_seed(seed)
     12 torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
     13 torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/cuda/random.py in cb()
    109         for i in range(device_count()):
    110             default_generator = torch.cuda.default_generators[i]
--> 111             default_generator.manual_seed(seed)
    112 
    113     _lazy_call(cb, seed_all=True)

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the accepted answer seems to be very strange. The presented code does not have anything to do with any tensor manipulation - it's just the initialization of the random generator.

From my experience this error might happen, when the environment is not properly initialized. I.e. cuDNN library might not be loaded or there is some other CUDA-related problem. In my case it was a missing call to include a Conda script (`source /net/software/v1/software/Miniconda3/4.9.2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`) which caused the error.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this error may occur because of some kind of inconsistency between the number of labels in your targets and the number of classes in your model.

To solve it you can try to:

1. Make sure that the label in your target data starts from 0. If you have n classes in your data, your target classes should be [0, 1, 2,..., n-1]
2. Make sure that the model you are using is set to work with n classes